# Flags: rename self-removed as retracted

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I see my flags summary page, retracted flags can be seen as *self-removed* status. Which I was seeing the first time, so I thought SO had added something new. I hovered over it and it displays the time. When I clicked on a link it was redirected to that retracted flagged question and there was *retracted flag 1* on the right side (where flag stats are shown).

**Question:**

Flag status as self-removed creates the confusion between post was removed by the author itself or the flagger has retracted the flag. (It might not create confusion for all, but when someone retracted the flag the first time, may confused.)

Can we have a single status or name as retracted?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58249329/10961238) you originally flagged is not a link-only answer - you were right to retract the flag as it's likely it'd be declined. The answer doesn't need the link to be useful.

Comment: Yes @WaiHaLee, but we should have a *single status* for that kind of flags